# discussion forum within BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

just wonder if it's doable to have app w/ functions like discussion forum so every project member can discuss project related stuff? i don't think BIM 360 already have such function, does it?
any Forge sample w/ similar function will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - there is no "chat" or "discussion" functionality in BIM 360. Collaboration for Revit used to have "chat features". But it was dropped. I assume that the product team still have plenty of design/construction specific features to prioritize. If our partners can do, it will be wonderful. I don't think there is any samples.
I remember one partner who joined the accelerator, (last year?), who had a project to integrating his chat features with some of forge functionality.
Are you looking to develop yourself?  Or potentially looking for integration partner?  If the latter, I may be able to dig out old e-mails find out a contact for you.

Comment: thanks Mikako, we're thinking to develop our own but don't know yet how to do it, will be great if you and/or your partner can give some advice.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area. But maybe WebSockets?

Comment: that's what i thought too, will be great if your Forge expert team can provide some samples.  the "chat features" of C4R is called Communicator if i remembered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just 4fun, script for creating folders in BIM360 http://project4871511.tilda.ws/ U can download this JS and using in your Forge APP

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.